# Which one is correct, As you mentioned or the other?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

In email, I need to respond with the meaning of 'I have made the changes as you mentioned in the below email'. I am not sure which one is grammatically correct. Can someone please help on this.

> As you mentioned below, I have made the changes accordingly.
>
> I have made the changes accordingly as you mentioned below.

Comment: Regardless of whether you put ***as you mentioned below*** before or after your primary statement, it still looks to me like a "sentence adverb" construction. Which imho means it's not a well-formed utterance, since the addressee definitely did NOT mention *the fact that you made the changes*.

Comment: You don't actually need all those words. All you have to say is, "I have made the changes you mentioned in the email below".

Comment: For my part, I reply with one word, "Done."